# How can we draw a Blaschke $3$ ellipse?

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, math-software, blaschke-products

Today I read the article [**Ellipses and Finite Blaschke Products**](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstor.org%2Fstable%2F3072367&ei=8MOkVJiWN8efugTw8YKQCQ&usg=AFQjCNGJqVx3bycWqweUHbU5JTM93g0LpQ&bvm=bv.82001339,d.dGc) by Ulrich Daepp, Pamela Gorkin, and Raymond Mortini.
In there they have proved very nice geometric results about  per-images of  Blaschke products which are fixed at zero of degree $2$ and $3$ on the unit circle.
Also in that paper they proved that the existence of marvelous geometric object called Blaschke $3$-ellipses which is looks like as in below.

[image]

[image]

Here I want to know about more geometrical properties of per-images of Blaschke  products (similar in the above paper). Is there any?

Also I wonder how we can draw the pictures like Blaschke $3$ ellipses.
How we can find a software to draw a Blaschke $3$ ellipses?
or Can we draw them using a common software (like MATLAB)? How?

My question may be not a good one, but I am very curious about this. Thank you.

Comment: In the paper they state "Using Mathematica, we studied several pictures of the points identified under a finite Blaschke product".

Comment: @Amzoti: Oh.. I have missed it. But I don't have an idea how we can use Mathematica to draw picture like this.

Comment: Mathematica is useful than Matlab in sense of drawing picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I'd plot your image in Mathematica.

```
B[a_, b_][z_] := z(z - a)/(1-Conjugate[a]z)(z-b)/(1-Conjugate[b] z);
compPts[a_, b_][lambda_] := 
   Quiet[Solve[B[a, b][z] == lambda, z], Solve::ratnz];
realPts[a_, b_][
   lambda_] := {Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ (z /. compPts[a, b][lambda]);
pic[a_, b_] := Graphics[{
    {Thick, Circle[]},
    {PointSize[Large], Point[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ {a, b}]},
    Line /@ 
     Table[Partition[realPts[a, b][Exp[I*t]], 2, 1, 1], {t, Pi/10, 
       2 Pi, Pi/10}]
    }];
pic[0.5, -0.4 + 0.4 I]
```

[image]

Now, the paper proves (as Theorem 1) that the envelope formed by those lines is exactly the ellipse with equation
$$\left|z-a\right|+\left|z-b\right|=\left|1-\overline{a}{b}\right|.$$
I suppose the geometric properties that you refer to spring forth from that equation.

Comment: I used your command and got this wonderful picture. I want to know more about mathematica. As you  think hat is the best reference about this software?

Comment: @Nilan I rather like Stan Wagon's [Mathematica in Action](http://goo.gl/4CSdLf). The reason is that the book focuses on *mathematics* first, thus, there's always an objective. I find it difficult to learn to program without an objective or project in mind. At some point, you'll want a more general introduction, I think that [Mathematica Programming](http://goo.gl/ag0sV7) is good (and free). Then, you need a good reference so definitely make use of the internal documentation. Finally, [this question](http://goo.gl/RAKjU7) on mathematica.se has plenty more references.